# Replaces Value in the first row

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I really need help in my add to cart function. The problem is that when i added product in the shopping cart the second time, it replaces the value in the first. It should be displayed in another row. Please help me. Thanks.

```js
    var qtyTotal = 0;
    var priceTotal = 0;
    var products = [];


    function addProduct() {
        var productID = document.getElementById("productID").value;
        var product_desc = document.getElementById("product_desc").value;
        var qty = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
        // qtyTotal = qtyTotal + parseInt(qty);
        //document.getElementById("qtyTotals").innerHTML=qtyTotal;
        var price = document.getElementById("price").value;

      var newProduct = {

          product_id : null,
          product_desc : null,
          product_qty : 0,
          product_price : 0.00,
      };
        newProduct.product_id = productID;
        newProduct.product_desc = product_desc;
        newProduct.product_qty = qty;
        newProduct.product_price = price;


        products.push(newProduct);

        //console.log("New Product " + JSON.stringify(newProduct))
        //console.log("Products " + JSON.stringify(products))

        var html = "<table border='1|1' >";
        html+="<td>Product ID</td>";
        html+="<td>Product Description</td>";
        html+="<td>Quantity</td>";
        html+="<td>Price</td>";
        html+="<td>Action</td>";
        for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        html+="<tr>";
        html+="<td>"+products[i].product_id+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+products[i].product_desc+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+products[i].product_qty+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+products[i].product_price+"</td>";
        html+="<td><button type='submit' onClick='deleteProduct(\""+products[i].product_id +"\", this);'/>Delete Item</button> &nbsp <button type='submit' onClick='addCart(\""+products[i].product_id +"\", this);'/>Add to Cart</button></td>";
        html+="</tr>";
    }
        html+="</table>";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = html;

        document.getElementById("resetbtn").click()            
}
    function deleteProduct(product_id, e) {
        e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode.parentNode);
        for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
                // DO NOT CHANGE THE 1 HERE
               products.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    function addCart(product_id){
        var html = "<table border='1|1'>";
        html+="<td>Product ID</td>";
        html+="<td>Product Description</td>";
        html+="<td>Quantity</td>";
        html+="<td>Price</td>";
        html+="<td>Total</td>";
        html+="<td>Action</td>";
        for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
            products[i].product_qty = parseInt(products[i].product_qty) + 1;
            html+="<tr>";
            html+="<td>"+products[i].product_id+"</td>";
            html+="<td>"+products[i].product_desc+"</td>";
            html+="<td>"+products[i].product_qty+"</td>";
            html+="<td>"+products[i].product_price+"</td>";
            html+="<td>"+parseInt(products[i].product_price)*parseInt(products[i].product_qty)+"</td>";
            html+="<td><button type='submit' onClick='subtractQuantity(\""+products[i].product_id +"\", this);'/>Subtract Quantity</button></td>";
            html+="</tr>";
        }    
    }
            html+="</table>";
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = html;

    }
    function subtractQuantity(product_id)
    { alert(product_id);
    for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (products[i].product_id == product_id & products[i].product_qty >= 1) {
            products[i].product_qty = parseInt(products[i].product_qty) - 1;
        }

        if (products[i].product_id == 0) {
            removeItem(products[i].product_id);
        }
        console.log("Products " + JSON.stringify(products));
        
    }
}

function removeItem(product_id) {
    for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
            // DO NOT CHANGE THE 1 HERE
            products.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shopping Cart Pure Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="order" id="order">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="productID">Product ID:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="productID" name="product" type="text" size="28" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="product">Product Desc:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="product_desc" name="product" type="text" size="28" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="quantity" name="quantity" width="196px" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="price">Price:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="price" name="price" size="28" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="reset" name="reset" id="resetbtn" class="resetbtn" value="Reset" />
    <input type="button" id="btnAddProduct" onclick="addProduct();" value="Add New Product" >


</form>
<br>
<p id="demo"></p> <br/>
<h2> Shopping Cart </h2>
<p id="demo2"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have edited your code and resolve your issue with the help of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Check below code. I have change it with javascript.

```js
var qtyTotal = 0;
    var priceTotal = 0;
    var products = [];


    function addProduct() {
        var productID = document.getElementById("productID").value;
        var product_desc = document.getElementById("product_desc").value;
        var qty = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
        // qtyTotal = qtyTotal + parseInt(qty);
        //document.getElementById("qtyTotals").innerHTML=qtyTotal;
        var price = document.getElementById("price").value;

      var newProduct = {

          product_id : null,
          product_desc : null,
          product_qty : 0,
          product_price : 0.00,
      };
        newProduct.product_id = productID;
        newProduct.product_desc = product_desc;
        newProduct.product_qty = qty;
        newProduct.product_price = price;


        products.push(newProduct);

        //console.log("New Product " + JSON.stringify(newProduct))
        //console.log("Products " + JSON.stringify(products))

        var html = "<table border='1|1' >";
        html+="<td>Product ID</td>";
        html+="<td>Product Description</td>";
        html+="<td>Quantity</td>";
        html+="<td>Price</td>";
        html+="<td>Action</td>";
        for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        html+="<tr>";
        html+="<td>"+products[i].product_id+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+products[i].product_desc+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+products[i].product_qty+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+products[i].product_price+"</td>";
        html+="<td><button type='submit' onClick='deleteProduct(\""+products[i].product_id +"\", this);'/>Delete Item</button> &nbsp <button type='submit' onClick='addCart(\""+products[i].product_id +"\", this);'/>Add to Cart</button></td>";
        html+="</tr>";
    }
        html+="</table>";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = html;

        document.getElementById("resetbtn").click()            
}
    function deleteProduct(product_id, e) {
        e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode.parentNode);
        for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
                // DO NOT CHANGE THE 1 HERE
               products.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    function addCart(product_id){
      var html = '';
      var ele = document.getElementById("demo2");     
      if(ele.innerHTML == '')
      {
        html+="<table id='tblCart' border='1|1'>";
        html+="<tr><td>Product ID</td>";
        html+="<td>Product Description</td>";
        html+="<td>Quantity</td>";
        html+="<td>Price</td>";
        html+="<td>Total</td>";
        html+="<td>Action</td></tr>";
      }
        for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
            products[i].product_qty = parseInt(products[i].product_qty) + 1;
            html+="<tr>";
            html+="<td>"+products[i].product_id+"</td>";
            html+="<td>"+products[i].product_desc+"</td>";
            html+="<td>"+products[i].product_qty+"</td>";
            html+="<td>"+products[i].product_price+"</td>";
            html+="<td>"+parseInt(products[i].product_price)*parseInt(products[i].product_qty)+"</td>";
            html+="<td><button type='submit' onClick='subtractQuantity(\""+products[i].product_id +"\", this);'/>Subtract Quantity</button></td>";
            html+="</tr>";
        }    
    }
      
      if(ele.innerHTML == '')
      {
        html+= "</table>";
        ele.innerHTML = html;
      }
      else
      {
        document.getElementById("tblCart").innerHTML += html;     
      }      
    }
    
    function subtractQuantity(product_id)
    { alert(product_id);
    for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (products[i].product_id == product_id & products[i].product_qty >= 1) {
            products[i].product_qty = parseInt(products[i].product_qty) - 1;
        }

        if (products[i].product_id == 0) {
            removeItem(products[i].product_id);
        }
        console.log("Products " + JSON.stringify(products));
        
    }
}

function removeItem(product_id) {
    for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
            // DO NOT CHANGE THE 1 HERE
            products.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shopping Cart Pure Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="order" id="order">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="productID">Product ID:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="productID" name="product" type="text" size="28" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="product">Product Desc:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="product_desc" name="product" type="text" size="28" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="quantity" name="quantity" width="196px" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="price">Price:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="price" name="price" size="28" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="reset" name="reset" id="resetbtn" class="resetbtn" value="Reset" />
    <input type="button" id="btnAddProduct" onclick="addProduct();" value="Add New Product" >


</form>
<br>
<p id="demo"></p> <br/>
<h2> Shopping Cart </h2>
<p id="demo2"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sir i was told to make it in Javascript only. Can you help me with that sir. Thanks you so much

Comment: You need to add just script for jquery. Its bit difficult to achieve it using javascript. Jquery have some inbuilt functions so its useful.

Comment: Yes sir I understand but my mentor told me to practice my javascript. So no jquery. Could you help me with that sir writing it in pure javascript?  Thank you so much sir

Comment: Sir, when you add the same product, it should increase its quantity and not add another row. Please help me with this sir and i would accept answer and + vote. Thanks sir

Comment: Its big task and you need to do it by some logic about it. I have resolve your question which you have posted. Its not as simple as you are thinking. Please accept this one and close it. If you want new answer paste your new question with your query. added +1 to your question. @charles

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = html;
```

Every time, that function is being called, you are changing the innerHTML of of 'demo2' whereas what you need to do is append to it. Use

```
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML += html;
```

Also, it is not a good idea to use the innerHTML property.It destroys references thus killing eventListeners or similar stuff linked to the object. Hope it helps !

Comment: then move those "heading" columns outside and keep them in html. Only append the table rows when needed. You could use JS to keep those table headers hidden until you append a row.

Comment: Can you edit my code sir and show it here? Thank you sir

Comment: I just told you the solution. I am not going to spoonfeed :)

Comment: Please sir. I badly needed it sir. Please :(

Comment: you just have to move the header stuff to html and keep the rows which add data in JS.

Comment: sir thats my problem. I dont know on how to write. Im just starting on how to learn javascript. Hope you understand. Thank you sir